# Alert dialog closed while rotating the screen

Tags: android

In an android app I have an alert dialog ,while rotating the screen it gets dismissed ,I have find lot of solutions in stack overflow similar to this but not for my issue...

This is my Alert Dialog coding...

```
private void callchangepswd() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.changepassword, null, false);

        EditText cemail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.chagepswd_mail);
        EditText cphone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.chagepswd_phone);
        Button verify=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.verifybtn);

        alertDialog.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog dialogShow = alertDialog.create();
        dialogShow.show();

        verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogShow.dismiss();
                newpassword();
            }
        });

    }
```

can anyone help to come out from this.....

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: what is configuration of your activity in manifest?

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

Answer (score 2):

No need to work with `SaveInstanceState`. You can save your activity state (including your dialog) after a device rotation by adding `orientation|screenSize` to your `android:configChanges` property of `activity`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

As it is correctly pointed out by @greenapps in the comment, you should add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to each activity where you call your dialog.

Comment: @SivaM, could you please tell us which device you use and which OS version the device has ?

Comment: You have to add this for every activity where you want to keep the alert dialog alive. Not only for main.

Comment: greenapps Thanks for the comments .

Answer (score 1):

When rotating the screen the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated. That is why your `Dialog` disappears.

In order to handle this situation you can override `onSaveInstanceState`, keep a `boolean` in the bundle telling you if the dialog was displayed. You should also keep the user input (phone and email).

And `onRestoreInstanceState` you need to recreate the dialog and fill the fields with the user input. You can read more about the activity lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: You should create one again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog, as said in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html DialogFragment will survive during orientation changes